# Is there a VBA Method of 'Releasing' a reference that also immediately removes the ldb (lock file)?

Tags: vba, ms-access, reference

**Scenario:**

Using a accde (or accdb) file as a library for common code (e.g. source.accde)

Other db's hold a reference to the library file.

I know and am able to remove the reference (either via VBA or "Tools..References") and confirm its removal in both the Project Explorer ('References' subfolder disappears) and under the Tools menu).

**Challenge:**

When the reference is created, a ldb lock file is created in the same directory as the library.  BUT, the lock file does not go away when the reference is removed (by VBA or by Tools menu) and persists until I fully close the database file that was referencing the library.  This means I can't copy over the library file (with e.g. a new version)

**Question / Looking for:**

Are there vba commands / alternative approaches to getting the lock file released when a reference is removed?  I understand from previous answers that the referenced project will remain in the vbe, and this might be the source of the lock?  Closing just the VBE doesn't change things (project remains until access itself is closed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you could, you shouldn't overwrite the library file as that would leave the main application uncompiled. And it also will, even if you close the main application and then overwrite the library file.

That's one of the limitations of library files.

The only reliable method is to distribute them as a pair: the main application compiled with its library file.

Comment: Hi Gustav - understood re: need to relink/compile from the main application once library file is overwritten.  In my particular use case, I am in development environment and in the process of developing the main app/ library pair in parallel; I often find my main app development work exposes small errors in the library, but then need to shut the whole main app down to go fix an error in the library.  I have a process for dropping and re-adding references, was hoping there was a way to stick with that and not have to shutdown the main app file.

Comment: There is no way around this. Setting the reference only indicates that the library file should be read, I guess. I have never worked with library files - it's faster and simpler just to import the objects needed.